# I'm trying to display an alert for wrong credentials entered, but only shows in the console

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuetify.js, alert

I've been trying to return an alert for when the user enters the wrong crenditials into the log in page.

The code i'm using is below:

```
<template>
    <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col md="4">
            <v-card elevation="2">
                <v-card-title>Login</v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-form
                    ref="form"
                    v-model="valid"
                    lazy-validation
                    >
                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="email"
                            :rules="emailRules"
                            label="Email"
                            outlined
                            required 
                        >
                        </v-text-field>

                        <v-text-field
                            v-model="password"
                            :rules="passwordRules"
                            label="Password"
                            outlined
                            required
                            :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
                            @click:append="show = !show"
                            :append-icon="show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                        >
                        </v-text-field>

                        <v-btn
                            elevation="2"
                            color="primary"
                            @click="login"
                        >
                            Login
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-form>

                    <p class="pt-2">Create an account? <router-link :to="{ name: 'Register' }">Register</router-link></p>
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>               
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            show: false,
            valid: false,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            emailRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Email is required',
                v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'Email must be valid'
            ],
            passwordRules: [
                v => !!v || 'Password is required',
                v => v.length >= 8 || 'Password must be 8 characters or more'
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            const valid = this.$refs.form.validate()
            if(valid){
                this.$store.dispatch('login', {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've been using google firebase and vuetify to create front end and store user information at the back end. When the user enters the wrong password/email the console logs an error as shown below:

Uncaught (in promise) t {code: "auth/user-not-found", message: "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.", a: null}

I want to display this message as an alert but cannot figure out how to. If anyone could help that would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$store.dispatch` returns a Promise, apparently makes a request to a backend server, which returns an erroneous i.e. non-200 response code. The promise is then rejected with the error returned by the backend. By catching any rejections you can handle them more smoothly, e.g.

```
this.$store.dispatch('login', {
  email: this.email,
  password: this.password
})
  .then((res) => { // do things on success })
  .catch((err) => { // do things on error });
```